# issues of recoding variable with ifelse

Tags: r

I want to recode the following variable, which have 1-5 points. And I want to recode the observations having score of 1 as 5, and the obs having score of 2 as 4, 4 as 2 , 5 as 1.
So I use the following codes, but these codes sometimes can give me the things I want, sometimes can't. Does anyone know how to make sure these code to achieve what I want? I'd be really appreciated of your replying.

```
str(cgss$c52)
dbl+lbl [1:0] 
@ label       : chr "[2 政党、政治团体或政治社团组织的活动] 在过去12个月里，您参加下列团体组织活动的频繁程度是："
@ format.stata: chr "%21.0g"
@ labels      : Named num [1:6] 1 2 3 4 5 8
..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "more than once a week" "once to three times a month" "less than 10 times during last year" "once durng last year" "never"

cgss$c52[cgss$c52==8] <- NA
table(cgss$c52)
   1    2    3    4    5  
  35  165  207  193 3609  
cgss$poliact <- ifelse(cgss$c52==1,5,
                   ifelse(cgss$c52==2,4,
                          ifelse(cgss$c52==3,3,
                                 ifelse(cgss$c52==4,2,1))))
table(cgss$poliact)
   1    2    3    4    5 
3609  193  207  165   35  # this is the output I want
```

sometimes it gives me this with completely the same codes

```
table(cgss$poliact)
< table of extent 0 >
```

Or does someone know how to do this in a better way?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
cgss <- cgss %>% mutate(poliact = recode(c52, `1` = 5, `2` = 4, `3` = 3, `4` = 2, `5` = 1))
```

If you want to include 8 = NA, add na_if()

```
cgss <- cgss %>% mutate(poliact = recode(c52, `1` = 5, `2` = 4, `3` = 3, `4` = 2, `5` = 1) %>% na_if("8"))
```

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `poliact`.
i `poliact = `%>%`(...)`.
x no applicable method for 'recode' applied to an object of class "c('haven_labelled', 'vctrs_vctr', 'double')"

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I got the above error messages with the  codes

Comment: Ok, I guess you imported data from SPSS. Use this code before running the solution above: `cgss$c52 <- haven::as_factor(cgss$c52)`

Comment: It still give me a error message, but I found car package can achiese what I want with `cgss$poliact <- car::recode(cgss$c52, '1=5; 2=4; 3=3; 4=2; 5=1')`